# Is it better to use a custom interface or well-known standard interface in an API?

Tags: .net, api, standards

I have a simple interface:

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    int Count { get; }
}
```

Users of my API will be forced to use this interface rather than ones they commonly know like `IList` or `IEnumerable`. I prefer this over `IList` because it only exposes members which can be used. I don't want all that `IsReadOnly` `Add()` `Remove()` `Insert()` unused junk polluting my API. And I prefer this over `IEnumerable` because my users will need access to an index and count. Is this sound reasoning, or should I just be using the more familiar `IList`? Why?

Comment: Since it implements IEnumerable users won't be forced to not use IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a better solution than implementing IList if your type would not actually implement all the members if IList.  You could implement IList and throw NotImplementedException but then you'd be violating Liskov.